# Authorization in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I've watched a lot of videos and read many blog posts on auth in GraphQL, and it appears that using Custom Directives seems to be the favourable solution to date.

I'm in the process of designing a web app and am reaching out to the JavaScript community to see whether what I am am pitching sounds sensible. Thanks in advance!

**Problem**

There is a large array of products available to a user. A new user will not have access to any of these, until an administrator has granted them access.

There is a tiered level of authorization, say tiers 0-5, and this data will be stored in a database that an API will called to fetch.

Suppose logged in user, A, loads the page. What we want to happen is get a list of all the products that a user has access to and their corresponding tier level for each product.

Once we click on a product, we want to return the products information, such as name, etc. The data being viewed on the page will come from multiple APIs. Certain components will not be rendered if their tier level is not high enough.

Comment: I don't really see a specific question in your post. If what you're asking is if it's possible to achieve what you described here using GraphQL, then _yes_ it is possible.

Comment: I agree with Claire. You should ask a clear question. This is possible though. You'd store the user in context, then check the user on context in each resolver before returning the appropriate data